What is the proper pronunciation of 血?
In the presentation of the following news item, Pang Ying (庞莹), a well-known news presenter of China National Radio, used two different pronunciations for the same word 血 that has greatly confused me as a listener and disturbed her reading as an anchoress：
8月15日晚，患者李某就诊于霸州市第二医院，需手术治疗。由于贫血(Xue4)达不到手术指征，先期给予输血(Xie3)治疗。8月16、17日，霸州市第二医院向廊坊市中心血(Xue4)站申请用血(Xue4)，先后两次共计给患者输注红细胞800毫升。8月18日，患者需要继续输血(Xue4)，廊坊市中心血(Xie3)站与霸州市第二医院均未顾及该患者为终身免费优先用血(Xue4)权益人，给患者带来极大不便。无偿献血(Xie3)证终身有效，不存在过期说法。问题发生后，我委责成相关单位立即整改，同时做好后续诊疗服务和用血(Xue4)保障工作。患者已于8月26日完成手术治疗，术后恢复良好。
Bio:
庞莹，中央广播电视总台央广十佳节目主持人，一级播音员。曾在两伊战争直播、三峡大坝系列直播、重返灾区直播等重大宣传报道中担任主播，2012年获中国播音主持金话筒奖，并获中国新闻奖等奖项十余个。
What is the proper pronunciation for the word 血?

See this question.

This question is similar to: 血: xuè , xiě, what's the difference?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you for the guidance. I wish if I knew then what I know now. No, I won't make any editing to my original question. A (great) news presenter is not supposed to read the same word of the same meaning in different sounds in the same text.

If you are not sure,xie3 won't be a problem.
The old literary formal version is xue4, but in practice,in daily life no one say xue4, and the more funny part is, when some people want to use formal version, they tend to pronunce it as xue3, which is totally wrong.
In conclusion, xue4 is the formal one, xie3 is the practical one, unless you know you are in a literary  and formal context（e.g. 流血xue4 牺牲）, you don't need to use xue4, since sounds weird from real world.

a good comparison in formal english is whom, a totally valid word but almost never used-- and when it is used its often used incorrectly even by natives.

The meaning of 血[xiě] is the same as 血[xuè], except the former is used more often in speaking language (口语).
https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%A1%80

Re: "except the former is used more often in speaking language (口语)." No, that's incorrect. xiě is the correct version, no matter if it's in speech, casual conversation, or other formal contexts, so long as it's verbally pronounced.

@Admirerofthedragonflag I only provided the info from a reputable source. Please click the link and check it out.

一般來說血的發音跟寫一樣，可能是北京腔唸起來比較字正腔圓，才有這樣的差異，但對native speaker來說都聽得懂！
